# customize combo box arrow in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to customize the WPF Combo Box arrow postion like this [image]

I google it. But i could not get any correct answer.

How can i customize the combo box arrow?

Comment: You have to override combobox complete control template to override that arrow. Control template sample can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @RohitVats has hinted, you will need to define a new `ControlTemplate` for your `ComboBox` control. You can find out how to define a new `ControlTemplate` in the [Customizing the Appearance of an Existing Control by Using a ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189093%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) article on MSDN. A good place to start is by implementing the default `ControlTemplate` and then customising it as you see fit. You can find the default `ControlTemplate` of the `ComboBox` in the [ComboBox Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx) page on MSDN.

Inside the default `ControlTemplate`, you will see a `ControlTemplate` defined for a `ToggleButton` control named `ComboBoxToggleButton`. In that `ControlTemplate`, you will find a `Path` named `Arrow`... *that* is the part that you want to replace:

```
<Path x:Name="Arrow"
      Grid.Column="1"
      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
      VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z" >
    <Path.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource GlyphColor}"/>
    </Path.Fill>
</Path>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. if i expand the combo box, the arrow should be changed. for this purpose can i use trigger?

Comment: Yes, you can use the [`ComboBox.IsDropDownOpen` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.isdropdownopen.aspx) in your `Trigger` which will return `True` when the popup is displayed... you *might* need to use a `DataTrigger` with a `RelativeSource FindAncestor Binding` to get hold of the `ComboBox.IsDropDownOpen` property from within the `ControlTemplate`... you *should* be able to find examples of this online.

Comment: what does Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z" mean?

Comment: @Hacki, that is the [Path Markup Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), which is a shorthand notation for drawing. In this example, it means Move to 0,0, then draw a Line to 4,4, then another Line to 8,0. The final Z ends the current figure and creates a line that connects the current point to the starting point of the figure.

Comment: You're very welcome. Sorry it took so long for me to respond. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <Path.LayoutTransform>
       <RotateTransform Angle="270" ></RotateTransform>
 </Path.LayoutTransform>
```

this is the simplest way to rotate